# Zero divisors in the extra-special group algebra $\mathbb{R}[2^{1+6}_+]$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Can you characterize the unit-group of the real group-algebra of the extraspecial plus-type 2-group of order 128?  (That is $\mathbb{R}[2_+^{1+6}]$ using Conway's notation.)

(Please choose any irrep you like.)

Failing that a characterization of the unit-group (or zero divisors) in either $\mathbb{C}[2_+^{1+6}]$ or $\mathbb{H}[2_+^{1+6}]$ would happily suffice.  The only solutions I know of for any field are in the local ring $\mathbb{F_2}[2^{1+6}_+$.

Failing that, I'll even take some "good references" on things that have worked in other contexts.

I'll be sure to cite all constructive feedback if this ever goes anywhere.

Thanks so much!

Comment: It depends what you mean by "characterize". All irreducible representations are realized over $\mathbb{R}$. So, $\mathbb{R}[2^{1+6}_+]\cong\mathbb{R}^{64}\times\mathbb{R}^{8\times 8}$.

Comment: Does the isomorphism above preserve the group-multiplication?

Comment: Progress would count as a method for finding all of the zero-divisors, or all the cancellative vectors of the group-ring.  We know for instance that for $g$ any of the group elements of order 4 that $1+g+g^2+g^3$ is a zero divisor; are all zero-divisors multiples of such elements or ore there others?  I want to form an equivalence $x\sim \lambda x, ~~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}[2^{1+6}_+], ~\lambda\in\mathbb{R}[2^{1+6}_+]^\times$, so at some point I need to be able to construct that unit-group, or at least its conjugacy class.

Comment: If choosing some particular irrep would make things any easier, by all means do so!

Comment: Yes, the isomorphism in my first comment is an isomorphism of algebras, so it maps units to units. Therefore, the unit group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^\times)^{64}\times\mathrm{GL}(8,\mathbb{R})$. Every non-unit is a zero-divisor and vice versa (counting 0 as a zero-divisor).